# How do you retrieve all the links in a TextView (or EditText)?

Tags: java, android

I want to retrieve an array of `Strings` that represent links within a `TextView`.

I understand I could use regex, but thought there could be an easier way, considering the Android SDK provides `Linkify`.

```
String[] links = textView.getLinks(); // Something like this.
```

So for example, if the text in the textView is...

"Yesterday I went to google.com and after some searches it led me to facebook.com."

I want to retrieve an array of value `["google.com", "facebook.com"]`.

Comment: Are there spaces between the links, and no spaces in the links?  You could just use `String.split(" ")` if so.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it more clear. The text doesn't only contain links, it has a variation of other words and punctuation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll  have a tough time doing this without a regex, as you're looking in a TextView that has mixed inputs. A quick google search has provided me with this regex for URLs:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$
```

Perhaps try something like this.

```
String userInput; //use a for loop to get each word from your textView and check each one.
String urlRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(userInput);
boolean b = m.matches();
```

If `userInput` is a random word from your input text b will be false, but if you parse through all the words one by one, every URL should result in a value of true for b.